# Why is xrandr reporting a resolution just above the maximum (native) resolution?

Tags: display, resolution, xrandr

I have a bizarre issue with a Lenovo e430 laptop.

The LCD display is 1366x768, but for some reason it always starts with a resolution of 1368x768. This 2px overscan makes things jump all over the place when you approach the edge.

xrandr does report that maximum size of the display to be 1368x768, which is irritating to say the least. The software is just doing what it thinks is right, and defaulting to the largest supported resolution.

Is my only recourse using ModeLines? I'd prefer the hardware actually report correctly. (who knows, it could be some hackjob of a 1368 panel..)

Comment: shouldn't the virtual screen size be much larger than your actual screen size? I would try setting a larger virtual screen in xorg.conf. Note: I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a failed(11.04 to 12.04) dist-upgrade, and a switch to plain Debian Testing, xrandr is reporting correctly.

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

All sorts of things that were not being detected before are now showing up, including refresh rates and the like.

I've obviously changed too many variables at once to make a concrete diagnosis.

Thanks to [Mik](https://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik) and [phipsalabim](https://askubuntu.com/users/132708/phipsalabim) for taking the time to edit and make suggestions.